# Where clause in PHP doesn't work with variable

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and have been trying to make this following work for some time but no luck.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM add_employee WHERE employee_id='".$employee_id."'";
```

I am getting this following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: employee_id in www/suman/payroll_process.php on line 12
```

I know the employee id I entered is in the database. When I hard coded employee_id='100', the query got a return.

How should I get the value in the variable and where should u this variable

Comment: Dude before the expression you need to define the $employee_id=100 or something//

Comment: Please note that PHP and SQL are different languages.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the PHP variable `$employee_id` in your script somewhere.

Also, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You're interpreting SQL & PHP wrong. Given:

```
... WHERE employee_id='".$employee_id."'
          ^---(A)---^    ^---(B)----^
```

(A) What's in the database
(B) What you're trying to find in the database

Since you're tryign to insert a PHP variable into the query string, you must have defined that variable elsewhere in your PHP code. Remember that while an SQL database and PHP can talk with each other, they must do so in each other's language. You can't send PHP code to a database and expect the database to execute it. That's not the database's job. The database interprets SQL queries and nothing else.

Similarly, when the database returns data back to PHP, the database driver must convert from the database-specific blob/text/date/enum fields into PHP versions. It's not PHP's job to try to interpret the database data formats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that employee_id is passed from a form, and not all servers automatically turn $_POST and $_GET to the corresponding variable. You would need to sort this out first

```
$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id']; // change to $_GET['employee_id'] if the value is shwn in the url
```

This would need to be included BEFORE you process your sql command.

Comment: It's worth noting that user input like this should *ALWAYS* be sanitized to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: definitely - sorry should have stated that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I try to train myself never to post something an inexperienced user could copy and paste and create a security liability :)